# Where or when to join the modifying clause?

Tags: pronouns

Source :[in the minddle paragraph](https://seekingalpha.com/article/4138365-fhfa-enters-gse-reform-debate-counter-cyclical-perspectives)

> > > I had the pleasure of running into John Paulson this past week where I got to introduce myself in passing.

This past week is a time ,not a place.

When is a time-relative pronoun that joins a modifying clause.
Where is a location-relative pronoun that joins a modifying clause.
For example:
The day when the concert takes place is Sunday.
The site where the concert will take place is Golden Gate Park.

Maybe the sentence :

> > > I had the pleasure of running into John Paulson this past week when I got to introduce myself in passing.

It is a typo in the article ?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call it entirely wrong, but I like *when* better than *where* here. The reason that it isn't entirely wrong is that presumably there was a place where the speaker ran into Paulson.

Suppose we add this:

> I had the pleasure of running into John Paulson this past week at the convention, where/when I got to introduce myself in passing.

As you can see, this sentence provides both a time and a place, and *where* or *when* work equally well.

Answer (score 0):

In this sentence, **where** is a conjunction. According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/where), as a conjunction, it can either mean **in a place that**, or **in a situation that**.

In your sentence, no place is referred to, but meeting John Paulson is a situation, and in that situation the speaker was able to introduce himself.

This meaning is used a lot in mathematics, for example:

> Transformations on rational functions **where** x is in the numerator and denominator